# Custom Master Page Referencing Controls in Code Behind

Tags: branding, custom-masterpage

I have built a custom SharePoint 2010 master page where I have dropped a standard asp.net DropDownList control.  I also have wired up a code behind file where I want to manipulate that control from.

However for reasons not apparent to me, I am NOT able to reference this control in the code behind.

```
this.myDropdown
```

Intellisense does not show it.  I cannot even get a handle on it using:

```
(DropDownList)Page.FindControl("myDropdown")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works!

```
(DropDownList)this.Page.Master.FindControl("myDropdown");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to refer your control normally in codebehind class for the master. Check the steps to create a code behind for the master page :

1)
Create a class inheriting from System.Web.UI.MasterPage.Declare the control in the class. For e.g.

```
 public class CustomMasterClass : System.Web.UI.MasterPage    
  {
        protected DropDownList myDropdown;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myDropdown.Width = 200;
        }
    }
```

2) Build it into a dll and add to GAC.

3) Add it to the safecontrols list on your web.config.

4) Add the same control to your master page as :

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="myDropdown" runat="server"/>
```

5)
Add reference to the class in your master. For e.g. :

```
<%@ Master language="C#" Inherits="CustomNamespace.CustomMasterClass, CustomNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ae015afe5f30fb68" %>
```